# Как вывести по одним значениям в таблице вывести другие (данные из одной таблицы)

Tags: mysql

Для изображенной схемы БД необходимо составить запрос, который вернет список всех счетов. Для каждого счета выбрать поля номер счета, дата счета, имя клиента и имя клиента, на которого ссылается клиент текущего счета.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня получилось вот так :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
select invoices.id,invoices.Billing_date,customers.Name from customers 
       left join invoices on invoices.Customer_id = customers.id;
```

Застрял на этом , вывести просто имена могу, а вот на кого ссылаются ума уже не хватает.

Comment: Замените фотографии на DDL таблиц и текст запроса. И вместо абстрактного *столбец на кого они ссылаются* указывайте конкретное поле конкретной таблицы. Пояснения размещайте не в комментариях, а в тексте вопроса (ссылка "править" под его текстом).

Comment: @Akina  я не знаю об существовании  DDL таблиц .

Comment: *я не знаю об существовании DDL таблиц* Ну так узнайте. [Data Definition Language (DDL)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language) вообще и [Data Definition Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-data-definition.html) конкретно для MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запрос не проверял, но Вам необходимо выполнить ещё один join на таблицу customers:

```
select Invoices.id,Invoices.Billing_date,Customers.Name,customers2.Name from Invoices
  left join Customers on Invoices.Customer_id = Customers.id
  left join Customers as customers2 on Customers.Referred_ID = customers2.Id
```

Comment: @Geslot
 Подскажите пожалуйста,    customers2     это как-бы еще одна переменнная?

Comment: @Akina Благодарю за подсказку. Теперь думаю должно быть правильно.

Comment: Получилось!!!!)

Comment: такая мелочь, а приятно, я 2 часа генерировал забросы)))

Comment: @Valvea Рекомендую  для понимания почитать про Алиасы в MySQL

Comment: непременно этим займусь!Но я так и не понял , как вы меня поняли, то есть что именно хочу?
Интересно я верно ответил вообще на поставленный мною вопрос?

Comment: @Geslot Кстати... а запросик-то неправильный! Если есть счёт, не привязанный к клиенту - фиг он будет выведен... А вот клиент без счетов, наоборот, с какого-то перепугу выведется. Направление связывания поправьте... `invoices left join customers left join customers as customers2`